# Use of `\bool_case`

Tags: interfaces

How do I use `\bool_case`?

In the following example I use `\int_compare` and `\int_case`. Here both commented out and working as expected.

I'm trying to use `\bool_case` to achieve the same. But I get an `Undefined control sequence` error (see below).

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \mycommand { m }
  {
    \seq_new:N \myseq
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \myseq { #1 }
    \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \myseq \myfunction:nn
  }

\cs_new:Nn \myfunction:nn
  {
    % \int_compare:nT { #1 > 1 } { > } #2

    % \int_case:nnF { #1 }
    %     {
    %         { 1 }{ #2 }
    %     }
    %     { > #2 }

    \bool_case:nF{
            {\int_compare_p:n {#1 = 1}}{ #2 }
        }
        { > #2 }
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\mycommand{1,2,3}
\end{document}
```

```
$ xelatex test.tex
This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999995 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-03-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\myfunction:nn #1#2->\bool_case:nF 
                                   {{\int_compare_p:n {#1=1}}{#2}}{>#2}
l.29 \mycommand{1,2,3}
                      
?
```

Comment: I get no error. Show your log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've updated my question with the output

Comment: your l3 layer is older than mine.

Comment: `\bool_case:n` needs at least L3 2023-05-03.

Comment: note the date of introduction is marked in `texdoc interface3` just under `\bool_case:nTF` in the left margin

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the packages to the latest version and it works as expected.